# PHP Swiftmailer: Write mail content and other information to DB after every mail sent

Tags: php, mysql, database, swiftmailer

I just discovered Swiftmailer for PHP and it seems to be working quite nicely.

However, during the sending of mails, I'd like to keep track of what has been sent and when, so I'd like to do some DB operations after every mail that has been sent. Any idea how I could achieve this?

I have the code for the database insertions etc. But I don't know, where to add this piece of code. I don't know where I have access to the individual mails.

I send it like this:

```
foreach($email as $id => $to) {
      $message->addTo($to);
}

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Somehow, I would have to access the individual mails.

*second edit* (because too broad):
The question is how I can perform an individual action after each email that has been sent in order to log the content sent, date and time for each receiver separately.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, thanks. But where should I write this code? Where do I have access to individual mails that are being sent? I cannot figure this out...

Comment: @Mario I don't know why your question has been downvoted, it's a perfectly legitimate question. I have not tried this myself but one way might be to use the logger plugin for swiftmail and make a custom logger that logs this in the database. Again, have not tried this myself. http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#logger-plugin

Comment: thanks @Oli for the support - the logger plugin is probably a good idea, but I don't know yet how write my own logger.... but thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @Mario, np mate. But I think you can do it, check out https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tree/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Plugins. MessageLogger seems like something you want. Copy, tinker, MyMessageLogger -> success :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this.

```
foreach($email as $id => $to) {
    Update Database here
    $message->addTo($to);
    $mailSending();
}
```

In your code, I am sure all email addresses  added in a single email and while you need to add a single email address in a single email and generate emails in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the excellent suggestion from Naveed, there is another solution that might work perfectly for you and that is the message logger.

It seems to me as it saves all the messages in memory so depending on number of messages you are sending it may or may not be a good fit.

So you add the logger to your mailer:

```
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(
    Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25)
);

$logger = new Swift_Plugins_MessageLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin($logger);
```

Then you send out your messages, these will be captured be the MessageLogger.

After which you can iterate through them and get the information you want for inserts or what have you:

```
$result = $mailer->send($message);

/* @var Swift_Message $msg */
foreach($logger->getMessages() as $msg) {
    var_dump($msg->getTo());
    var_dump($msg->getFrom());
    var_dump($msg->getSubject());
    var_dump($msg->getBody());
    var_dump($msg->getDate());
}
```

Hope that helps.